# Status/Navigation Bar not Displayed correctly on Startup - Edge To Edge

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, edge-to-edge

I've just replaced a deprecated accompanist `SysteUiController` with an Activity Component's `Edge to Edge`. And it works just fine. However I've noticed that during a startup status/navigation bars don't look the way they should. Even if it's only for a second, I was wondering if there's a way to avoid that somehow?

The first image shows how it looks like on startup.

[image]
[image]

**MainActivity:**

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        enableEdgeToEdge(
            statusBarStyle = SystemBarStyle.light(
                Color.TRANSPARENT, Color.TRANSPARENT
            ),
            navigationBarStyle = SystemBarStyle.light(
                Color.TRANSPARENT, Color.TRANSPARENT
            )
        )
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            CompTestTheme {
                MainScreen()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Root composable:**

```
...
if (!view.isInEditMode) {
    SideEffect {
        val window = (view.context as Activity).window
        window.statusBarColor = Color.Transparent.toArgb()
        WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, view).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = !darkTheme
    }
}

MaterialTheme(
    colorScheme = colorScheme,
    typography = Typography,
    content = content
)
```

Comment: Is your theme's parent a NoActionBar (like `Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar`) one?

Comment: @GergelyKőrössy Yes, NoActionBar indeed: "android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar"